# Хранение разреженной матрицы в разреженном строчном формате (CSR или CRS)

Tags: алгоритм, численные-методы, псевдокод

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм упаковки разреженной матрицы в разреженном строчном формате (Compressed Sparse Rows или Compressed Row Storage) и способ доступа к элементам упакованной матрицы.

Матрица должна храниться в виде трех одномерных массивов:

- **A**. Все ненулевые элементы с первой до последней строки;
- **LJ**. Номер столбца (j-индекс) каждого ненулевого элемента
- **LI**. Позиция первого ненулевого элемента в каждой строке (i-индекс). Если в строке i встречаются только нулевые элементы (строка является пустой), то значение LI[i] = LI[i + 1]. Если матрица А состоит из N-строк, то длина массива LI будет (N + 1).

Ответ можно в любом виде: блок-схема, псевдокод, исходный текст программы на любом языке.

Answer (score 1):

Проще показать на примере.

Пример с использованием SciPy (модуль/библиотека для Python):

```
In [113]: from scipy.sparse import random, csr_matrix
```

создаем матрицу размерности (`7 x 7`) со случайными элементами:

```
In [114]: M = random(7, 7, .1, 'csr')

In [115]: M
Out[115]:
<7x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Массив ненулевых значений матрицы:

```
In [116]: M.data
Out[116]: array([ 0.88229169,  0.06023865,  0.30738982,  0.91385742])
```

Массив индексов столбцов ненулевых элементов:

```
In [117]: M.indices
Out[117]: array([2, 5, 6, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Массив указателей (для `M.data` и `M.indices`) на ненулевые элементы в строках:

```
In [118]: M.indptr
Out[118]: array([0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Матрица в обычном развернутом виде:

```
In [119]: M.A
Out[119]:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.88229169,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.06023865,  0.30738982],
       [ 0.91385742,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Для первой строки (`i = 0`):

```
In [120]: i = 0

In [121]: M.data[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[121]: array([ 0.88229169])

In [122]: M.indices[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[122]: array([2], dtype=int32)
```

Для второй строки (`i = 1`):

```
In [123]: i = 1

In [124]: M.data[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[124]: array([ 0.06023865,  0.30738982])

In [125]: M.indices[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[125]: array([5, 6], dtype=int32)
```

Для третьей строки (`i = 2`):

```
In [126]: i = 2

In [127]: M.data[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[127]: array([ 0.91385742])

In [128]: M.indices[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[128]: array([0], dtype=int32)
```

Для четвертой строки (`i = 3`):

```
In [129]: i = 3

In [130]: M.data[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[130]: array([], dtype=float64)

In [131]: M.indices[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[131]: array([], dtype=int32)
```

Для пятой строки (`i = 4`):

```
In [132]: i = 4

In [133]: M.data[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[133]: array([], dtype=float64)

In [134]: M.indices[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]]
Out[134]: array([], dtype=int32)
```

...

Comment: Библиотека прикольная, но не совсем то, что мне нужно. Нужен не готовый функционал, а нужно понять как реализовать самому этот алгоритм. За ответ все равно спасибо :)

Comment: @fedor-sg, сохранить данные в таком виде не так уж и сложно - из моего ответа видно как это делается в SciPy, но как вы собираетесь реализовывать все операторы (+,-,*,/) с другими матрицами, векторами и скалярами? Причем все эти операции надо стараться делать не разжимая матриц, а это далеко не всегда возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Для хранения данных с избыточностью в общем случае применяется архивирование. Так что сжимайте свои данные (матрицы это или не матрицы) своим любимым архиватором и горя не знайте. Благо что библиотек для всяких алгоритмов сжатия-разжатия есть на любой вкус цвет и размер для любой платформы и любого языка.

Comment: Это понятно, но опять же не совсем то, что нужно. Нужна конкретика на поставленный вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот на c++. (не компилировал, могут быть ошибки)

```
double eps = 0.000001;

vector<vector<double>> m; // пусть это прямоугольная матрица
int height = m.size(),
    width = m[0].size();

vector<double> A();
vector<int> aJ();
vector<int> aI({0});

for (int i = 0; i < heght; i++)
{
    aI.push_back(aI.back());        

    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        if (abs(m[i][j]) < eps) continue;

        A.push_back(a[i][j]);
        aJ.push_back(j);
        aI[i + 1] ++;
    }
}
```

Теперь доступ

```
for (int i = 0; i < aI.size() - 1; i++)
for (int k = aI[i]; k < aI[i+1]; k++)
    cout << "A(" << i << ", " << aJ[k] << ") = " << A[k] << endl;
```